# C++ File Closure in try/catch block

Tags: c++, file, try-catch

Is it correct? to write:

```
try {
  fstream file;
  file.open(....);
  f(x);   // this function may throw an exception
  ...
  file.close();
} catch {
  ...
}
```

I want to know if the file will be closed if the function inside the try block throws an exception?

Comment: Yes, it will, because the file objects destructor will do so.

Comment: Btw, *closure* means something else in C++ ...

Answer (score 0):

First, your call `file.close();` is unnecessary: omitting it makes no difference, since the object `file` will be closed upon destruction anyway.

Second the destructor for `file` will be called in any case, whether an exception is thrown in the `try` `catch` block or not.